# Bash extended globbing inside a Makefile

Tags: bash, make

I want to do an operation on all the files in a particular folder that do not start with a particular prefix (say `exclude_`). I have a bash `for` loop with an extended glob that looks like this:

```
for FILE in foo/bar/!(exclude_*) ; do echo $FILE ; done
```

On the command line, this works fine:

```
 $ for FILE in foo/bar/!(exclude_*) ; do echo $FILE ; done
 foo/bar/apple
 foo/bar/pear
 foo/bar/banana
```

But, when I use it in a makefile:

```
target:
    for FILE in foo/bar/!(exclude_*) ; do echo $$FILE ; done
```

I get the following error:

```
$ make
for FILE in foo/bar/!(exclude_*) ; do echo $FILE ; done
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `for FILE in foo/bar/!(exclude_*) ; do echo $FILE ; done'
```

Is there some necessary escaping that I've missed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. You need to set `extglob`.
2. You need to tell make to use bash, not sh.

#### Makefile:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
.SHELLFLAGS="-O extglob -c"
 ...
```

Comment: Hmm. For some reason the `.SHELLFLAGS` didn't work for me, but putting the flags directly in `SHELL=/bin/bash -O extglob -c` did. Any ideas why?

Comment: Maybe you're not using GNU make. Or maybe it doesn't need the quotes.

Comment: GNU Make 3.81, and GNU bash, version 4.1.2. Tried without the quotes too. Weird.

Comment: Anyway, your answer solved it for me once I put them all on the one line. Thanks!

Comment: @TimothyJones Hi, I tried your method. But why I got errors? SHELL=/bin/bash -O extglob -c
/bin/sh: -O: command not found
make: *** [mpip] Error 127

Comment: I was trying to use `SHELL := /bin/bash +O extglob`, but that didn't work. I wonder why. Your method didn't work for me, though, either. I got "`/bin/bash: - : invalid option`."

Comment: The `.SHELLFLAGS` variable was added in GNU make 3.82.  You can check which features were added in which releases via the NEWS file: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/NEWS

Comment: `.SHELLFLAGS` worked for me with GNU Make 3.82, but only without the quotes

Answer (score 13):

It would be more idiomatic and more portable to solve this with Make and not with Bash hacks. What if someone doesn't have Bash installed?

Anyway, here's the [proper way](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#index-filter_002dout-577) to do it in Make:

```
FOOFILES = $(filter-out foo/bar/exclude_%,$(wildcard foo/bar/*))

target:
    for FILE in ${FOOFILES}; do echo $$FILE ; done
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simpler way:

```
SHELL:=/bin/bash -O globstar
```

which will enable globstar shell option (which works on BSD/OS X as well).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of the Makefile:

```
SHELL := bash -O extglob
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The above version is correct.